# How to Create a User in nested serializer using generic ListCreateAPIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am working on genericAPIViews in DRF. I am using a built in user model with UserProfile model having one to one relation with it. But I am unable to create user due to nested serializer. My question is that how I can create my built in User model and Profile User model at the same time as UserProfile model is nested in User model.Here is my code:

Models.py

```
USER_CHOICE = (
    ('SS', 'SS'),
    ('SP', 'SP')
)
LOGIN_TYPE = (
    ('Local', 'Local'),
    ('Facebook', 'Facebook'),
    ('Google', 'Google')
)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default="", null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="", null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="", null=True)
    profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to='user_images/', default='', blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="", null=True)
    registration_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # roles = models.ForeignKey(Role, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='role', blank=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=USER_CHOICE, null=True, blank=True)
    login_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=LOGIN_TYPE, default='local')
    reset_pass = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    remember_me = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reset_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default="")
    reset_code_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=80, decimal_places=10, default=0.00)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=80, decimal_places=10, default=0.00)
    r_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    refer_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="user_refer")
    referred = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="user_referred", null=True, blank=True)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, default="", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']
```

Views.py

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer



class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

I know there is .create() method which can be override according to DRF documentation. Plus I want to override this method in views.py. Is there any approach to do this. Thanks in advance for your addition in my knowledge.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have created a view to creating `User` and now looking for a way so that when `User` is created, an `UserProfile` will also be created for that user, right?

Comment: Exactly! but using genericAPIviews. My APIview is working fine when I create a user only but issue comes when I nest UserProfile serializer in User build in model.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing that in my knowledge.

The first one is overriding the create method of the generic view. Which is as follows:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        #let django create the user with generic view
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # response.data contains the serialized data of the created user
        user_data = response.data
        user_id = response.data.get("id")

        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        profile.save()
        
        # return the response created by the generic view
        return response
```

Be careful that Django Rest Framework does not support the `create` method for nested serializers. Set the profile field to read-only in `UserSerializer`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']
        read_only_fields = ('profile',)

    def get_profile(self, user):
        profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        return UserProfileSerializer(profile).data if profile is not None else None
```

The second way is using signals. Signals is an event dispatcher that keeps track of events such as update, delete, m2m changed, etc. Here, we can use `post_save` signals which trigger whenever a model gets updated. So if the `User` model is created, we will receive a signal and therefore crate a `UserProfile` for that user. You can learn more about signals from the [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) page.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="create_user_profile")
def on_user_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    
    # here instance is the user object that just got created
    # created is a boolean value which will be true if the record is newly created
    if created:
        
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = instance
        profile.save()
```

Comment: my code is crashing at here:
response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `myapp.serializers.UserSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

Comment: remove the `profile` field from `UserSerializer` . DRF does not support `create` method for nested serializers.

Comment: well thanks for helping.But i know this and was trying if there is any method to override create() method and perform this task.

Comment: I have updated my snippet. Please try this now.

Comment: Thanks but I need to create userprofile when ever user is created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228908/discussion-between-iftieaq-and-moiz-ul-waqar).